# Using a Xbox One Kinect on a Turtlebot

Tags: kinect, rviz, turtlebot, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After searching around I couldn't find anything on this topic, so I thought I would post this here. I am relatively new to the Turtlebot scene, and I am working with a Kobuki base operating with an Asus laptop running Ubuntu 12.04. I am curious if anyone has tried to integrate the new Xbox One Kinect onto the Turtlebot platform?

If anyone has, was it worth it? Would it be directly replaceable?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187283/using-a-xbox-one-kinect-on-a-turtlebot/) by [anonymous34234](https://answers.ros.org/users/19801/anonymous34234/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-07-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Would it be directly replaceable?

Simple answer: No.

So far I've seen no working Linux integration of the new Kinect.

Even the Clearpath guys use a work around. [See here.](http://hackaday.com/2014/07/21/cutting-ribbons-with-robots-and-a-oculus-rift/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+hackaday%2FLgoM+%28Hack+a+Day%29) They connect the Kinect to a Windows PC and send only the data to Linux.

But you're not alone waiting for ROS integration of this device.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2014-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anonymous34234](https://answers.ros.org/users/19801/anonymous34234/) on 2014-07-22**:
I figured that was the case. Thank you for your answer.

**Comment by [srik11](https://answers.ros.org/users/25636/srik11/) on 2016-01-17**:
Hi!,
Have you been able to get the new kinect (kinect for xbox one) run on Linux?. I have been facing some issues. I figure it must be because of the usb incompatibility. I am using a usb 3.0 port but still face issue.
Wanted to know whether you have been able to get it work.
Thanks for your time.